# How to combine CSV files in R and add the file name as a column header

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I am a newbie to R but I have been given a large dataset to work with and I am wondering whether I can do this process in R instead of manually. I have a folder with about 600 hundred csv files with two columns and no headers. Each csv file has the same first column but a different second column, I would like to combine them in the form detailed below:

File1.csv

1|A
2|A
3|A
4|A

File2.csv

1|B
2|B
3|B
4|B

And I would like to combine them to:

ID|File 1|File 2

1|A|B
2|A|B
3|A|B
4|A|B

the current code I have is:

```
library("dplyr")                                                
library("plyr")                                                 
library("readr")  

data <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv) %>%                                           
  bind_rows                                                      

data
```

This works to an extent, however, since the data does not have headings, it puts the first data value as the column heading like this.

1|A|B

2|A|B
3|A|B
4|A|B

Which will result in me manually having to input headers. I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: You may need to specify `col_names = FALSE` i..e `lapply(read_csv, col_names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to join your data rather than unite it. Does the following solve your problem?

```
library(tidyverse)

my_read <- function(x) {
    tmp <- read_csv(x, col_names = FALSE)
    names(tmp) <- c("id", x)
    tmp
}

data <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map(my_read) %>%                                           
  reduce(left_join)
```

First you can create a small function to read your data in without headers and assign the file names as the 2nd column name.

`reduce()` comes from `{purrr}` (as does `map()`), and will iteratively apply a function to elements in a list. In this case, we'll keep `left_join()`'ing our data together (on whatever your common 1st column is) until we get a single dataframe.

Comment: That's perfect! I understand where I went wrong now. Saved me hours of work, Thank you!