# Is there a way to give a column header the name of the file in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, merge, columnheader

I have a bunch of csv files that need to be merged into one file. They all have the same first column and column B is unique to each file. The other issue I have is that they don't have column headers. I am trying to give column B the name of the file so when they are merged, I can tell which time point each column is.
Currently, I have files that look like this:

| 399        |  0.1887   |

| 400        |  0.1298   |

| 401        | -0.1249   |

Ultimately, I want my file to be like this:

| Wavelength | 137.5uU 0 | 137.5uU 1 | 137.5uU 2 |

| 399        |  0.1887   |  0.1489   |  0.2676   |

| 400        |  0.1298   |  0.2988   | -0.0298   |

| 401        | -0.1249   | -0.1397   |  0.1293   |

I was able to make a file with the second column of data for all my files using this code:

```
csv_files <- list.files(path="C:")

abs <- do.call(cbind, lapply(csv_files, function(x) {
    setNames(data.frame(read.csv(x)[[2]]), tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x)))
  }))
```

I was then writing the new file into a folder with my T0 file where I would merge the two files with this code:

```
df <- list.files(path="C:/", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
   lapply(read_csv) %>% 
   bind_cols()
```

The problem I am running into here is that the first code is overwriting the first row of data for the headers so the # of rows in my T0 and my abs files are not aligned. Also, the first code is making a column that numbers the rows and will be imported as data in the next file.

I did also try the solutions in this thread and could not get them to work.

[How to combine CSV files in R and add the file name as a column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72059957/how-to-combine-csv-files-in-r-and-add-the-file-name-as-a-column-header)

Comment: Do you mean the first column name is identical for each file or the all rows are indentical in each file for column one? I would rename the second column like this: ```list.files() %>% 
  purrr::map(
    .x = .,
    ~ readr::read_csv(.x, col_names = F) %>% 
      dplyr::as_tibble() %>% 
      dplyr::rename(.x = V2) %>% 
      readr::write_csv()
  )``` and then you just need to get the path together with the file name to read in the data

Comment: There are currently no column names, but column A is identical in all files and column B is the data that is unique to each file.

Comment: use `setNames(csv_files)` in place of `csv_files` in your `do.call(...)` expression. To clean it up, you might prefer to instead use `setNames(csv_files, sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(csv_files)))` for a slightly more refined step.